# I am trying to make Use s!help <command> for more info on the command but it doesent work

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using discord.py and want something like Use s!help  for more info on the command. the bot runs without any error but this part doesn't work

````
async def kick(ctx):

  embed = discord.Embed(title="Kick", description="Kicks a member. Only used by users having kick members permission")
  embed.add_field(name = "**Syntax**", value = "s!kick <member> (reason)")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, A few things here.

This question is not really supportive in providing much code.

Next time give the reader an understanding of how the help command works.
Assuming that you are probably using `client.command()` you would need to define it as a command not just `async def` put something like `client.command()` before the `async def` then it will work as a command.

Otherwise, if that did not help I am completely misled on how your command works, and how you want it to work.

Example

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Kick", description="Kicks a member. Only used by users having kick members permission")
  embed.add_field(name = "**Syntax**", value = "s!kick <member> (reason)")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Also I noticed again you said it was for a help command, what you would wanna do then is make a `help` group like this

`client.group(invoke_without_command=True)`
`async def help(ctx):`
  etc.

Then make a command called `help.command()` and put the kick code below it.