# How to assign a sub-help for a command discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

How To assign a sub-help for a command in discord.py?

```py
class xkcd(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def hi(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('hey')
```

when I type <!help hi> it should show more info about the command.
how can I do this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879317/i-am-trying-to-make-use-shelp-command-for-more-info-on-the-command-but-it-doe) out. There is a comment in the answer which should help you out.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "sub-help". Do you mean you want to add a help message for the `hi` command using the default discord.py `help` command implementation?

Comment: @Taku by sub-help, I mean if you do 
prefix help <name of the command>,
it should show more info about the command.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options depending on what you want to show and where you want to show it, but I will give the important ones. `brief` and `description` allow you to specify, as you may expect, a brief description and full description for the command. They are parameters of `@client.command()` and would be placed `@client.command(HERE)`. In your case, that would be `@commands.command(HERE)`.

> ADDITION: As [Taku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622817/taku) mentioned, the `help` parameter would also
> allow you to do what you want. `@commands.command(help="")` lets you
> define the long text for the help message, which in effect, will do
> both `brief` and `description` at once. Use this if you do not need to
> differentiate between the two descriptions.

The `brief` will give you a brief description when running the `!help` command with no arguments given. Output from the bot shown here:

```
​No Category:
  help  Shows this message
  hi    This is where the BRIEF would be found.

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

The `description` will set the message when the command is passed as argument to the default help command, in your case: `!help hi`. The output from the bot would show as:

```
This is where the DESCRIPTION is found.

!hi
```

So, to conclude, your new code would look like this:

```
class xkcd(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
  self.bot = bot

@commands.command(brief="This is where the BRIEF would be found.", description="This is where the DESCRIPTION is found.")
async def hi(self, ctx):
  await ctx.send('hey')
```

Simply change the strings to what you want for each command.

I'd also recommend reading the docs on the matter, found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#command). That will go over all the arguments for the command() function, and it is always nice to know all the options you have.

edit: Saw the comment clarifying what you meant by sub-help

Comment: The main "body" of the help message is with the `help` argument or supplied as the doc-string for the function. `description` is only the top line of the help message. Perhaps you should mention the simplest doc-string method and the `help` argument.

Comment: @tkomasa but this is for the default help command of discord. I have already made a custom help command and disabled the default help command. Is there another way to provide description to a command by doing 
prefix help <command> ?

Comment: @MockingJay That is unfortunately a different question and important info you should have provided. I would recommend making a new question with more examples and a clearer statement of what you need. Provide your current code for the custom help command in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try creating another command called `help_hi` then in the aliases call it `help hi` so it calls it without the `_`**

*Example:*

```
  @commands.command()
  async def hi(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('hey')

  @commands.command(aliases = ["help hi"])
  async def help_hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Using `!hi` will make the bot respond with `hey`")
```

*Or you can imply the help part like this:*

```
  @commands.command(help = "Want <bot_name> to say hi? Use `!hi`")
  async def hi(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('hey')
```

So now when you run the command `!help` the default help embed discord apply for you will show it!

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
class xkcd(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def hi(self, ctx):
    """
    This is the description for my very cool command.
    Have a very good day!
    """
    await ctx.send('hey')
```

Docstrings are used to add documentation to functions, and they are used in discord.py for the purpose of `!help <command>`.

The first line of the docstring will be used as the 1liner in `!help`, so in this case it'll be listed as:

```
hi    This is the description for my very cool command.
```

`!help hi` will display:

```
!hi 

This is the description for my very cool command.
Have a very good day!
```